# Infinite scroll in React

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm trying to add infinite scroll in my component. I somehow did it but it is not working as expected. Whenever, I scroll to bottom it adds more data to `APIData` but it just duplicates the data which has been already fetched instead of adding new data. And, even when I'm at bottom, the scroll function still runs and fetching the data again and again which has already been fetched. And I'm also getting a warning that I didn't include `getData` in the dependency array. What's happening and why?

```
export default function News({ category }) {

    const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([])

    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)

    const pageSize = 20

    async function getData() {
        let response = await fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=${category}&pageSize=${pageSize}&page=${page}&apiKey={APIKey}`)
        let parsedResponse = await response.json()
        setAPIData(APIData.concat(parsedResponse.articles))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [category])

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
        if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight && page === 1) {
            setPage(2)
            getData()
            console.log('working')
        }
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be most likely due to this https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

You can verify that what the page no while in the getData function by console

```
async function getData(category,page) {
    let response = await fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=${category}&pageSize=${pageSize}&page=${page}&apiKey={APIKey}`)
    let parsedResponse = await response.json()
    setAPIData(APIData.concat(parsedResponse.articles))
}

useEffect(() => {
    getData(category,page)
}, [category,page])

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight && page === 1) {
        setPage(2)

        console.log('working')
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked but what about the scroll behavior? It still runs the function inside of scroll event listener even when I'm at the bottom of the page and all data has loaded and page is set as 2 but still running

Comment: instead of making your own component i would like to recommend you to use community based component like this one
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component

Answer (score 1):

Add new items to state as follow:

```
setAPIData(previousState => [...previousState, ...parsedResponse.articles])
```